# question on asymptotes of rational functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I know that I have a vertical and slant asymptote but I don't know how to find the coordinates for the max or min of the two functions or the coordinate of the vertical asymptote.

Can someone please provide me with a hint on how to prove the statement? There aren't any numbers for me to actually play around with.

Comment: Treat $a, b, c$ and $d$ as numbers. Find $f'(x)$ and set it to zero to find the $x-$coordinates of the turning points. You may also need to find the conditions on $a, b, c$ and $d$ so that the graph has the given form.

Comment: Alternatively, you could show that the graph has point symmetry about the intersection of the two asymptotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x) = \frac{ax^2 - 2adx - (bd+c)}{(x-d)^2}$

When $f'(x) = 0, x = d \pm \gamma,$ where $\gamma$ is some function of $a, b, c$ and $d$.

[The actual value of $\gamma$ is not important.]

The $x-$coordinate of the midpoint of the two turning points [if they exist] is:

$\frac{1}{2}[(d + \gamma) + (d - \gamma)] = d$

This is also the $x-$coordinate of the intersection of the two asymptotes, since the vertical asymptote is $x = d$.

Comment: how do you know the vertical asymptote is d?

Comment: The denominator $(x-d)$ can never be zero.

Comment: oh duh, sorry that was dumb